# implicit messages compile error in play2.5

Tags: scala, playframework, implicit

I have a play2.5 app and a form where i would like to have the error messages internationalized. I have the form in a separate object and use it in the controller. But play dos not compile because could not find implicit messages.

I suppose this is a trivial solution but I'm new to play and scala, and would be grateful for any hint.

Error:(14, 45) could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages
      "username" -> email.verifying(Messages("error.email.required"), {!_.isEmpty}),

```
object LoginForm {

  val form = Form(
    mapping(
      "username" -> email.verifying(Messages("error.email.required"), {!_.isEmpty}),
      "pasword" -> nonEmptyText(8,20).verifying(Messages("error.password.required"), {!_.isEmpty})
    )(Data.apply)(Data.unapply)
  )

  case class Data(
    username: String,
    password: String
  )

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `I18nSupport` trait to get the implicit `play.api.i18n.Messages` value in scope.  Full explanation here:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaI18N#Externalizing-messages

For your use-case, the simplest approach would be to define the form inside of a controller which uses the `I18nSupport` trait.  As you're new to Scala and Play I'd recommend this approach.

A more advanced approach would be to define the form in a `LoginForm` trait and declare a dependency on the `I18nSupport` trait.  This would look like:

```
trait LoginForm{
  self: I18nSupport =>

  //define form here
}
```

Then you would just mixin this `LoginForm` trait to the controller you need it in (which should be mixing in the `I18nSupport` trait).

Comment: tnx, I was also thinking to move the form inside the controller, but seemed more elegant to have it outside in a different file, I will try the suggested solution tnx

Comment: i have done the trait as mentioned but it cann not resolve symbol  I18nSupport ... what should i import ? I have tried import play.api.i18n.I18nSupport but it does not work

Comment: What version of Play are you running?

Comment: I am running the 2.5 version of play

Comment: I just created a vanilla Play 2.5 Scala app via Activator, the following import resolved without issue: import play.api.i18n.{I18nSupport, MessagesApi}.  Double-check your code.

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong but I'm not able to resolve the dependency :( ... se on the link

https://snag.gy/yi7AkT.jpg

I will define the form inside the controller for now

Comment: ahh now I see it should be self: I18nSupport => not ... self: => I18nSupport    .... I will accept your answer ... tnx very much for taking your time

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you implicitly provide lang to the form like this?

```
def form(implicit lang: Lang) = Form(
    mapping(
      "username" -> email.verifying(Messages("error.email.required"), {!_.isEmpty}),
      "pasword" -> nonEmptyText(8,20).verifying(Messages("error.password.required"), {!_.isEmpty})
    )(Data.apply)(Data.unapply)
  )
```

It can sometimes be nice to move the form to the companion object of the case class:

```
case class Data(
    username: String,
    password: String
  )

object Data {
  def form(implicit lang: Lang) = ...
}
```